# pass variables of add_action" to do_action - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have this add_action function that creates an array in the following way.

```
add_action( 'mixedcart', 'checkoutincluyenevio', 1, 2 );
function checkoutincluyenevio() {
$mensaje['label'] = "Incluye Envío";
$mensaje['price'] = null;
$mensaje['style'] = "background-color:#e4f4fd;font-weight:initial;";
$mensaje['class'] = "mixedcar";
return $mensaje;
}
```

This code is in the functions.php file of my theme.

In a template of my theme I want to retrieve the values by doing this.

```
$checkoutincluyenevio = do_action( 'mixedcart' );
```

I obtain as a result the variable $checkoutincluyenevio as NULL

The expected result would be the variable `$mensaje` with all its content.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If this is the only time it is used, it would probably be better as a normal function rather than adding an action or a filter.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer for variables better use the filters
apply_filters and add_filter

it would stay this way

```
add_filter( 'mixedcart', 'checkoutincluyenevio', 10, 2 );

function checkoutincluyenevio($mensaje) {
$mensaje['label'] = "Incluye Envío";
$mensaje['price'] = null;
$mensaje['style'] = "background-color:#e4f4fd;font-weight:initial;";
$mensaje['class'] = "mixedcar";
return $mensaje;
}
```

In template

```
$checkoutincluyenevio = apply_filters( 'mixedcart', $mensaje );
```